# PostgreSQL cmd output

Tags: postgresql, cmd, output

While working with PostgreSQL I have faced the following problem. An output which is returned into command line in not readable. It consists of symbols which do not make sense.

I execute the command: `initdb --help`. The output is attached.

[image]

Comment: My guess: initdb is printing help using cyrillic alphabet but cmd is unable to show it properly.

Comment: `chcp 65001` and try again